# Vibration during Deceleration

Tags: manual-transmission, vibration, drivetrain, intermittent-problems, lancer

I have a 2001 Mitsubishi Lancer CE, I recently replaced the clutch as the release bearing was no longer servicable.

After replacing the clutch I noticed during deceleration a vibration like noise. [At approx 12 seconds here](https://soundcloud.com/brok9n/noise), I take my foot of the throttle in 2nd gear going down a hill. I've noticed the higher the RPM the louder / higher frequency of the noise, also it seems much worse going downhill vs flat ground.

When I push the clutch pedal in (disengage the clutch) the noise stops immediately. And when I reapply sufficient throttle to accelerate the noise also disappears.

I don't think it's the clutch as I imagine that would also occur while accelerating. But it definitely appears to be drive line related. Also I confirmed the transmission oil level is full after I noticed the noise.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: If you're sure it's coming from driveline, check for play on the CV joints and bearings. Driveline noises should change/develop proportionally to speed, not engine revs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have the flywheel resurfaced? If while in gear and moving if pushing the clutch in and out the noise changes it is most likely right there.

Answer (score 0):

Pump fluid in the clutch! there on the release cylinder next to the box there is a fitting for pumping! you have air in the system! the rod does not fully move the plug

Also check clutch pedal adjustment